# How to set <title> of a client component in Next 13?

Tags: next.js, seo, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I'm migrating my Next 12 app to Next 13 and its new `/app` directory.

I have a `<LoginPage>` component (rendered @ `/login`) and obviously, it needs to use hooks to manage form data. As such, I have marked it with the `'use client'` directive.

However, that means that the new metadata API can't be used to set the `<title>`, which ideally, I'd like to be something as simple as `Login | ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_NAME}`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For now I think the only way is to split your component into a parent server component with the metadata config and a children client component with everything else. Check this git issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46372

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `Metadata`, you can put the `<title>` tag directly into `page.js` among your components.

```
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <title>Page title</title>

      <OtherComponent />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: yes, exactly, and if you want a description or anything else just add the correspondent html tag like so <meta name="description" content="my description" />

Comment: It works but quite ugly. You will see 2 <title> tags in the code.

Answer (score 3):

You could use layout in `login` directory.

[image]

inside layout:

```
import React from "react";
// this is server component. you could use `metadata` as well
const layout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <title>Login to my app</title>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 'use client' inside page.tsx, you can use useEffect to set the title in client side.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Your New Page Title";
  }, []);
```

This is best way by now when we work with Nextjs 14 App Router.